# Check if an element on a page is not hidden from real users?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Using PHP/Javascript, is it possible to check whether an element (let's say a link) exists **AND is actually VISIBLE by a real person** on a remote website?

I know it's possible to check if a link/element exists in a source of a page (via using cURL or file_get_contents() function), but it may happen an element is hidden behind a `<style="display:none">{element}</style>` CSS style or class or between `<script>` or comment tags - then it won't show up for a public user.

So I wanted to check if it's possible to find out if an element is visible in a source code, but not visible to an actual/real user. It's probably impossible but wanted to make sure..

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options:

1. using javascript (and jQuery) to check for visility and hidden tags
   see: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ and https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/
2. Recreate the page in a DOMDocument and iterate the nodes to check for attributes that make the element not visible. see: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

The second option is a short answer, it would take multiples step to get it done and i'm not sure how since i never made it myself but studying the manual make me say it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the target is cross-domain you can accomplish this by scraping the external page into a php holder page using `curl`, then loading that php holder page as a jQuery Ajax function and the `:hidden` selector.

**holder.php**

```
 $ch = curl_init("http://www.foo.com/bar");
 $html = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $html;
```

**page.php or page.html**

```
 $.get('holder.php', function (data) {
     hidden_tags = $(data).find('a:hidden');
 });
```

Comment: There's also an Ajax Cross Origin jQuery plugin that would cut one step out of the process: [http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/)